# How to parent components of a rig made with rigify to things other than the mesh?

Tags: modeling, rigging, parent, rigify, pose-mode

I have created (with some help) a rig using rigify and a mesh. I want to pair something to some of the parts of the rig (specifically, a ring on the finger that moves with the finger). Is there a means to parent components of my rig to this object to allow for the object to move with the rig?

Comment: Hello, you can either parent your ring to some vertices of the mesh, like the finger, or you can parent the ring to the bone that controls the finger

Comment: Hi, whenever I try to parent to a vertex I get the error 'Select either 1 or 3 verticies to parent to'

Comment: yes you need to select 3 vertices of your finger: select your ring object, shift select the body, switch to Edit mode, select 3 vertices, parent. But you could also join the ring to the body mesh with Ctrl J, select the ring mesh with L, then assign to the vertex group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control it

Comment: You can also join the ring to the finger or use a child-of constraint.  The first is the least useful.  The second is good if you want to sometimes 'take the ring off'.

Comment: Would this second approach would mean that the ring would become a part of the mesh? If I was working on doing something similar with a heart model that lies within the mesh (such that when the mesh is animated to become transparent the heart is visible internally) would this technique still work?

Comment: what technic will you use to make the body transparent?

Comment: I would use a transparency node under shading and then decrease the alpha value of the mesh.

Comment: The heart can be part of the same object but you can give it another material